# I using @Autowired interface service in Spring Boot return null

Tags: spring-boot

I do not understand why - even though I have declared @Autowired - my service is null.

```
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

/**
 * Get info User login
 */

public HashMap<String, Object> getUserInfo() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String userName = (String) authentication.getName();
    User user = userService.findUserByUserName(userName); //userService is null

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("user", user);        
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Show your class definition and how spring context initialized/configured

Comment: Updated the question with code for the service and the interface

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not instantiated object of interface implementation anywhere else in your code base.

Example of what you should **not** write while using @Autowired:

```
IUserService userService = new IUserServiceImplementation();
```